# p:tabView restting after opening a p:dialog from one of the tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using `p:tabView` to display multiple pages in different tabs.

At one of the tabs I'm opening a `p:dialog`(I even tried with javascript `window`), As soon as the dialog or window opens the entire `p:tabView` component is getting reset.

The ManagedBeans in some of the tabs are `@ViewScoped` so its became huge scope related problem.

In the following code I'm just recreating the scenario in less code as possible(my ManagedBeans and Xhtmls are bigger than in following code).

Please provide any solution or workaround to overcome this problem if you have faces same problem.

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:tabView dynamic="true"> 
            <p:tab title="Tab1">
                <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Tab2">
                <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**tab1.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{tab1Bean.tab1BeanString}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**tab2.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{tab2Bean.tab2BeanString}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <p:button onclick="dlg.show()"/>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">
        <ui:include src="popup.xhtml"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

**popup.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{tab2Bean.tab2BeanString}"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{tab2Bean.popupString}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Tab1Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Tab1Bean implements Serializable{

    private String tab1BeanString="default String";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Tab1 Bean PostConstruct");
    }

    public Tab1Bean() {
        System.out.println("Tab1 Bean Constructor");
    }

    public String getTab1BeanString() {
        return tab1BeanString;
    }

    public void setTab1BeanString(String tab1BeanString) {
        this.tab1BeanString = tab1BeanString;
    }

}
```

**Tab2Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Tab2Bean implements Serializable {

    private String tab2BeanString;
    private String popupString;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        System.out.println("Tab2 Bean @PostConstruct");
    }

    public Tab2Bean() {
        System.out.println("Tab2 Bean Constructor");
    }


    public String getTab2BeanString() {
        return tab2BeanString;
    }
    public void setTab2BeanString(String tab2BeanString) {
        this.tab2BeanString = tab2BeanString;
    }

    public String getPopupString() {
        return popupString;
    }
    public void setPopupString(String popupString) {
        this.popupString = popupString;
    }
}
```

*Using: Primefaces 3.5 and Mojarra 2.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p:tabView` component is not resetting, its just navigating to first tab.
Since your Tab1Bean is in `@ViewScope` its calling the `@PostConstruct` and `Constructors` again.
Make the same tabs as selected tab after opening window using `p:tabView`'s Clisntside javascript functions:

```
(PrimeFaces.widget.TabView).select(index)
```